# angular-file-upload temporarily disabling drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-file-upload

I am using angular-file-upload (https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)
I would like to disable the drag and drop functionality once the upload process has begun so that more files cannot be added to the queue. Any ideas how I can do this? Ultimately I would like to be able to disable the drag-and-drop and then possibly re-enable it after onCompleteAll but I'd settle for being able to simply disable the functionality completely once isUploading == true

Answer (score 0):

you can add a watch for uploader.isUploading and when it's true you can set the queueLimit to 1.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/README.md) you can add `ngf-drop-disabled="boolean"` to your form. Setting it to `true` after the first upload has completed should solve your problem.